# how to run block of code inside python case statement

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, case, switch-statement

I'm new to python and I really like concept of using dictionaries instead of switch/case statements, but there is one problem I can't figure out

Let's say we have a 'pythonic case' statement

```
{
    'a': somemethod,
    'b': othermethod
}['a']()
```

This works fine, but I can't figure out how to run some block of code like in other languages like java, something which would look like this

```
{
    'a': { some commands here }
    'b': { other commands here that are executed }
}['a']
```

Maybe lambda could help?

Thank you so much

Comment: Python doesn't have a switch statement, give it up trying to graft one on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary values have to be objects of some kind. This means that you essentially must encapsulate the code you want to run within a function defined elsewhere. You *could* toy with `exec` -- you could create a dict of strings, and then `exec` a string from the dict, for example --  but I wouldn't recommend it.

`lambda` does partially answer your question, but `lambda` is limited in its applicability; it can only create one-line functions, among other limitations. Still, for very simple functions, it is adequate.

```
>>> d = {
...      'a': lambda: 5 + 5,
...      'b': lambda: 10 + 10
...     }
>>> d['a']()
10
```

The best way to do this with longer blocks of code is simply to define a function or method.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `if...elif...else`. It's not that bad:

```
    if x == 'a':
        pass
    elif x == 'b':
        pass
    elif x == 'c':
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your code into functions. You could then create a dictionary of functions but there is already a concept to do that for you in Python: use a class.

```
class Foo:
   def cmd_a(self): ...
   def cmd_b(self): ...
   def cmd_c(self): ...
   def default_action(self): ...
   def execute(self, cmd):
       action = getattr(self, 'cmd_'+cmd, self.default_action)
       return action()

foo = Foo()
foo.execute('a')
```